# Cellar Hazelcast serialization exception when using DOSGi service

Tags: java, osgi, hazelcast, apache-karaf, dosgi

I've made an application with the following three bundles

- **`myservice-api`**

  - contains model class to transport data `de.myservice.api.model.MyObject`
  - contains service interface `de.myservice.api.services.MyService` with function `void save(MyObject o)`
- **`myservice-impl`**

  - contains an implementation for `MyService` and provides it via DOSGi
- **`frontend`** is just some code that references to the `MyService` implementation via blueprint and calls the `save` function

I created a cluster using the Apache Cellar feature with two Karaf servers on different machines. The bundles are deployed like this and show the status `Active`:

- machine001.company.int

  - `myservice-api`
  - `frontend`
- machine002.company.int

  - `myservice-api`
  - `myservice-impl`

When using `cluster:list-nodes` it shows that the cluster is set up, using `cluster:service-list` I can see that my service is provided by machine002:

```
Service Class                       | Provider Node
-----------------------------------------------------------------
de.myservice.api.services.MyService | machine002.company.int:5701
```

The OSGi linking and stuff works, but when the `frontend` tries to use the `save` function, I get the following exception on the service providing instance `machine002`:

```
2017-03-14 12:55:02,250 | WARN  | pool-65-thread-1 | QueueConsumer                    | 328 - org.apache.karaf.cellar.hazelcast - 4.0.3 |
CELLAR HAZELCAST: consumer task failed to poll the queue com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.myservice.api.model.MyObject
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:46)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:172)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:103)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:74)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:158)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.QueueProxySupport.invokeAndGet(QueueProxySupport.java:177)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.QueueProxySupport.pollInternal(QueueProxySupport.java:124)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.QueueProxyImpl.poll(QueueProxyImpl.java:88)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        at org.apache.karaf.cellar.hazelcast.QueueConsumer.run(QueueConsumer.java:93)[328:org.apache.karaf.cellar.hazelcast:4.0.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.myservice.api.model.MyObject
        at org.apache.karaf.cellar.core.utils.CombinedClassLoader.findClass(CombinedClassLoader.java:79)[326:org.apache.karaf.cellar.core:4.0.3]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_45]
        at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:151)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:120)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:358)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:1149)[:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)[:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)[:1.8.0_45]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:219)[322:com.hazelcast:3.7.2]
        ... 12 more
```

The `myservice-api` bundle is deployed on both machines so the class should be available - is there something else I must configure so that hazelcast knows where to take the classes from for de/serialization?

Comment: I think the problem is obvious ´Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.haba.genex.exp.automation.api.model.AutomatedExport` which means the class cannot be loaded by Hazelcast. How did you create the HazelcastInstance? It doesn't seem to have access to the BundleClassloader.

Comment: @noctarius the Cellar feature does all the work of setting up the Hazelcast cluster. I know that this is obviously the problem, but I can't find any info on how to configure Cellar to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your api bundle actually doesn't export the required packages. 
Therefore make sure it really does. And since it's working on the "server" side, 
I'm sure your implementation bundle might have those API packages included. So make sure your exports/imports etc. for your bundles is correct.